# I can't get the previous month total in power bi. I am very new to Power Bi. Below is my code

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

Inventory summary is an excel workbook that was imported. I have a Calendar table and I have Inventory Summary.date linked.

```
Hardware Inventory Prior Month =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Inventory Summary xls'[Value] ),
    FILTER (
        'Inventory Summary xls',
        'Inventory Summary xls'[Description] = "Hardware"
    ),
    DATEADD ( 'Inventory Summary xls'[Date], -1, MONTH )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok. Are you sure you did the modeling correct?

Also please check that your date table is marked as date table. Go to Data View --> Table tools --> Calendars --> Mark as Date Table see picture:

[image: MArk AS date table]

Note: Write your filter argument like this:(Iterate only what you need! not the whole fact table :))

```
Hardware Inventory Prior Month =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Inventory Summary xls'[Value] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Inventory Summary xls'[Description] ),
        'Inventory Summary xls'[Description] = "Hardware"
    ),
    DATEADD ( 'Inventory Summary xls'[Date], -1, MONTH )
)
```

Comment: My Calendar table is marked correctly. I added the FILTER(ALL(...as you suggested. It still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Are you sure you did the modeling correct?"

Comment: Did you check the datatypes of matched columns ?